# git clean -X behaviour when .gitignore has sub-directory entries

Tags: git, gitignore

When using sub-directory entries in .gitignore, "git clean -X" doesn't clean the ignored sub-directory.

```
$ git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/jpgariep/git/test/.git/
$ cd test/
$ mkdir -p a/b/c
$ touch a/b/c/test
$ echo '/a/b/' > .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m "Added .gitignore."
[master (root-commit) 94e2825] Added .gitignore.
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$ git clean -X -d -f
$ ls a
b
```

Why is b still there?

Git version: 1.7.2.3

NOTE: This was also posted on the git mailing list 2 months ago without answer.

Comment: I am missing something here... You ask git to ignore /a/b and you are surpirised it ignores /a/b ? I my interpretation correct or am I missing a subtelty?

Comment: The ignoring is working Ok.  The problem is with the "git clean -X" command.  The -X option with git clean is supposed to clean files that are ignored.  "git clean -X -d -f" should act as a "make clean".

Comment: 'git clean -x -d -f' works fine. But I understand you want to keep the a directory which was made, but not committed. It looks like a bug. a workaround is to commit everything on a local branch and use small x to clean

Comment: I really want -X and not -x as I want not-yet-commited files to remain in the workspace.  It smells the bug, I agree.

Comment: I've reposted this on the git mailing.  We'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's a bug.

http://marc.info/?l=git&m=128561999924671&w=2